# Выравнивание заголовков столбцов таблицы по середине

Tags: html, c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap, razor

Во View моего проекта, для таблицы не получается установить выравнивание заголовков по середине, но значения столбцов получается:

**EditElLearn.cshtml**

```
    @using WebApplication1.ViewModels;
    @model WebApplication1.ViewModels.Monit10ElListVM

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "EditElLearn";
    }

    ...

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.ElCode)
        int rowNumber = 0;

        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" cols="6" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" align="center">
            <tr bgcolor="#efefef">
                <th align="center"> № п/п </th>
                <th align="center" width="20%"> Фамилия </th>
                <th align="center" width="18%"> Имя </th>
                <th align="center" width="14%"> Отчество </th>
                <th align="center" width="12%"> Класс </th>
                <th align="center" width="14%"> % выполнения элемента содержания по КИМ ОГЭ-2015</th>
                <th align="center" width="14%"> Коррекционная оценка</th>
ОГЭ-2015</th>
                <th width="14%"> Коррекционная оценка</th>
            </tr>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Monit10Learnes.Count; i++ )
            {
                rowNumber++;
                <tr bgcolor="#efefef">
                    <td align="center">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => rowNumber)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Monit10Learnes[i].Surname)
                    </td>                    
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Monit10Learnes[i].Name)                    
                    </td>                    
                    <td>                     
                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Monit10Learnes[i].SecondName)
                    </td>                    
                    <td align="center">      
                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Monit10Learnes[i].ClassName)
                    </td>                    
                    <td align="center">      
                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Monit10Learnes[i].ValueOge15)
                    </td>                    
                    <td align="center">      
                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Monit10Learnes[i].RatingValue)                    
                    </td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Monit10Learnes[i].RatingID)                
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-0">
                <input type="submit" value="Сохранить" class="btn btn-success" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Знающие люди предлагают использовать CSS:

```
text-align: center;
```

Потому что использование атрибутов align и valign в блоках , , и  были исключены в HTML 5. Они были исключены в пользу CSS для выравнивания текста. Вместо этого, CSS имеет выравнивания текста, которые распространяются на инлайн-содержимое блочных элементов.

Более подробно с информацией можно ознакомится [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13992170/2546083)

Как вариант - можно написать так:

```
<th class="not_mapped_style" style="text-align:center">DisplayName</th>
```

Answer (score 1):

С тем, что любой css приоритетнее этого устаревшего атрибута. Где-то есть css-стиль, делающий выравнивание по левому краю. Используй css для стилизации таблицы.

И вообще, стоп.
Ты только первый заголовок пытаешься выровнять по середине, а остальные - нет.

Comment: я исправил - теперь идет попытка выравнить все заголовки. Все равно не помогает.

Comment: @adamshakhabov, я же сказал, у этого атрибута, который вообще надо забыть, приоритет меньше, чем у того, что вешает бутстрап. Насколько я помню, тебе надо прописать что-то типа `.table > tbody > tr > th { text-align: center; }`, причём `.table` лучше заменить на свой класс.